# how can I get the effect of sliding up boxes in random

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I did search all around the web to find away to make this effect on this website http://www.kissfmuk.com/

the boxes that move up and down. I could not find away to make it nor with CSS and jQuery. Thanks

Comment: If you inspect the elements that move, in IE, Chrome and FF press F12. You can see that the site uses an animation with a background:
    background-image: url("../img/bar-bg-kisstory.jpg");
    -webkit-animation: cleanDesktopAnimation 0.95s infinite;

Comment: Thanks man that was helpfull